# LLDB: How to define a function with arguments in .lldbinit?

Tags: debugging, lldb

I would like write a helper function which to be available in my LLDB session. (I am not talking about python here)
This function will invoke methods of current program variables and then pass them to a python script.
I guess i understand how to write a python script, but i am still not sure how to write an lldb-script which interacts with my program.

Answer (score 1):

For a general intro on how to use the lldb Python module to interact with your program, see:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html

That will show you some different ways you can use Python in lldb, and particularly how to make Python based commands and load them into the lldb command interpreter.

There are a variety of example scripts that you can look at here:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/examples/python

There's an on-line version of the Python API help here:

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api.html

and you can access the same information from within lldb by doing:

```
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()' or Ctrl-D.
>>> help(lldb)
Help on package lldb:

NAME
    lldb

FILE
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python/lldb/__init__.py

DESCRIPTION
...
```

Comment: For a matter of fact, and i should have said that, my question is about adding a C helper function. "command alias" isn't very helpful since it's more complex when it comes to arguments and i want to have a function which does some actual work.

Comment: All three links broken. Consider updating the answer?

Comment: Fixed, but these links show up in a bunch of other answers, and I don't have the time to go hunt them down and fix them...